# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jax-ws

I have following script which is used to post comments. But when I try to submit the comment Google Chrome throws this error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

jax.processResponse

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange

I simply don't know what this error is all about.

```
function Jax() {
    var loadingTimeout = 400;
    var iframe;
    this.loadingFunction = function () {};
    this.doneLoadingFunction = function () {};
    this.stringify = function (arg) {
        var c, i, l, o, u, v;
        switch (typeof arg) {
        case "object":
            if (arg) {
                if (arg.constructor == Array) {
                    o = "";
                    for (i = 0; i < arg.length; ++i) {
                        v = this.stringify(arg[i]);
                        if (o && (v !== u)) {
                            o += ","
                        }
                        if (v !== u) {
                            o += v
                        }
                    }
                    return "[" + o + "]"
                } else {
                    if (typeof arg.toString != "undefined") {
                        o = "";
                        for (i in arg) {
                            v = this.stringify(arg[i]);
                            if (v !== u) {
                                if (o) {
                                    o += ","
                                }
                                o += this.stringify(i) + ":" + v
                            }
                        }
                        return "{" + o + "}"
                    } else {
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
            return "";
        case "unknown":
        case "undefined":
        case "function":
            return u;
        case "string":
            arg = arg.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
            l = arg.length;
            o = '"';
            for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
                c = arg.charAt(i);
                if (c >= " ") {
                    if (c == "\\" || c == '"') {
                        o += "\\"
                    }
                    o += c
                } else {
                    switch (c) {
                    case '"':
                        o += '\\"';
                        break;
                    case "\b":
                        o += "\\b";
                        break;
                    case "\f":
                        o += "\\f";
                        break;
                    case "\n":
                        o += "\\n";
                        break;
                    case "\r":
                        o += "\\r";
                        break;
                    case "\t":
                        o += "\\t";
                        break;
                    default:
                        c = c.charCodeAt();
                        o += "\\u00";
                        o += Math.floor(c / 16).toString(16);
                        o += (c % 16).toString(16)
                    }
                }
            }
            return o + '"';
        default:
            return String(arg)
        }
    };
    this.getRequestObject = function () {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            http_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
        } else {
            if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                var msxmlhttp = new Array("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0", "Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0", "Msxml2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                for (var i = 0; i < msxmlhttp.length; i++) {
                    try {
                        http_request = new ActiveXObject(msxmlhttp[i])
                    } catch (e) {
                        http_request = null
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (!http_request) {
            alert("Unfortunatelly you browser doesn't support this feature.");
            return false
        }
        return http_request
    };
    this.$ = function (sId) {
        if (!sId) {
            return null
        }
        var returnObj = document.getElementById(sId);
        if (!returnObj && document.all) {
            returnObj = document.all[sId]
        }
        return returnObj
    };
    this.addEvent = function (obj, type, fn) {
        if (obj.attachEvent) {
            obj["e" + type + fn] = fn;
            obj[type + fn] = function () {
                obj["e" + type + fn](window.event)
            };
            obj.attachEvent("on" + type, obj[type + fn])
        } else {
            obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false)
        }
    };
    this.removeEvent = function (obj, type, fn) {
        if (obj.detachEvent) {
            obj.detachEvent("on" + type, obj[type + fn]);
            obj[type + fn] = null
        } else {
            obj.removeEventListener(type, fn, false)
        }
    };
    this.submitITask = function (comName, func, postData, responseFunc) {
        var xmlReq = this.buildXmlReq(comName, func, postData, responseFunc, true);
        this.loadingFunction();
        if (!this.iframe) {
            this.iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
            this.iframe.setAttribute("id", "ajaxIframe");
            this.iframe.setAttribute("height", 0);
            this.iframe.setAttribute("width", 0);
            this.iframe.setAttribute("border", 0);
            this.iframe.style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.body.appendChild(this.iframe);
            this.iframe.src = xmlReq
        } else {
            this.iframe.src = xmlReq
        }
    };
    this.extractIFrameBody = function (iFrameEl) {
        var doc = null;
        if (iFrameEl.contentDocument) {
            doc = iFrameEl.contentDocument
        } else {
            if (iFrameEl.contentWindow) {
                doc = iFrameEl.contentWindow.document
            } else {
                if (iFrameEl.document) {
                    doc = iFrameEl.document
                } else {
                    alert("Error: could not find sumiFrame document");
                    return null
                }
            }
        }
        return doc.body
    };
    this.buildXmlReq = function (comName, func, postData, responseFunc, iframe) {
        var xmlReq = "";
        if (iframe) {
            xmlReq += "?"
        } else {
            xmlReq += "&"
        }
        xmlReq += "option=" + comName;
        xmlReq += "&no_html=1";
        xmlReq += "&task=azrul_ajax";
        xmlReq += "&func=" + func;
        xmlReq += "&" + jax_token_var + "=1";
        if (postData) {
            xmlReq += "&" + postData
        }
        return xmlReq
    };
    this.submitTask = function (comName, func, postData, responseFunc) {
        var xmlhttp = this.getRequestObject();
        var targetUrl = jax_live_site;
        xmlhttp.open("POST", targetUrl, true);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    jax.doneLoadingFunction();
                    jax.processResponse(xmlhttp.responseText)
                } else {}
            }
        };
        var id = 1;
        var xmlReq = this.buildXmlReq(comName, func, postData, responseFunc);
        this.loadingFunction();
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send(xmlReq)
    };
    this.processIResponse = function () {
        jax.doneLoadingFunction();
        var resp = (this.extractIFrameBody(this.iframe).innerHTML);
        resp = resp.replace(/&lt;/g, "<");
        resp = resp.replace(/&gt;/g, ">");
        resp = resp.replace(/&amp;/g, "&");
        resp = resp.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
        resp = resp.replace(/&#39;/g, "'");
        this.processResponse(resp)
    };
    this.BetterInnerHTML = function (o, p, q) {
        function r(a) {
            var b;
            if (typeof DOMParser != "undefined") {
                b = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(a, "application/xml")
            } else {
                var c = ["MSXML2.DOMDocument", "MSXML.DOMDocument", "Microsoft.XMLDOM"];
                for (var i = 0; i < c.length && !b; i++) {
                    try {
                        b = new ActiveXObject(c[i]);
                        b.loadXML(a)
                    } catch (e) {}
                }
            }
            return b
        }
        function s(a, b, c) {
            a[b] = function () {
                return eval(c)
            }
        }
        function t(b, c, d) {
            if (typeof d == "undefined") {
                d = 1
            }
            if (d > 1) {
                if (c.nodeType == 1) {
                    var e = document.createElement(c.nodeName);
                    var f = {};
                    for (var a = 0, g = c.attributes.length; a < g; a++) {
                        var h = c.attributes[a].name,
                            k = c.attributes[a].value,
                            l = (h.substr(0, 2) == "on");
                        if (l) {
                            f[h] = k
                        } else {
                            switch (h) {
                            case "class":
                                e.className = k;
                                break;
                            case "for":
                                e.htmlFor = k;
                                break;
                            default:
                                e.setAttribute(h, k)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    b = b.appendChild(e);
                    for (l in f) {
                        s(b, l, f[l])
                    }
                } else {
                    if (c.nodeType == 3) {
                        var m = (c.nodeValue ? c.nodeValue : "");
                        var n = m.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, "");
                        if (n.length < 7 || (n.indexOf("<!--") != 0 && n.indexOf("-->") != (n.length - 3))) {
                            b.appendChild(document.createTextNode(m))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            for (var i = 0, j = c.childNodes.length; i < j; i++) {
                t(b, c.childNodes[i], d + 1)
            }
        }
        p = "<root>" + p + "</root>";
        var u = r(p);
        if (o && u) {
            if (q != false) {
                while (o.lastChild) {
                    o.removeChild(o.lastChild)
                }
            }
            t(o, u.documentElement)
        }
    };
    this.processResponse = function (responseTxt) {
        var result = eval(responseTxt);
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            var cmd = result[i][0];
            var id = result[i][1];
            var property = result[i][2];
            var data = result[i][3];
            var objElement = this.$(id);
            switch (cmd) {
            case "as":
                if (objElement) {
                    eval("objElement." + property + "=  data ; ")
                }
                break;
            case "al":
                if (data) {
                    alert(data)
                }
                break;
            case "ce":
                this.create(id, property, data);
                break;
            case "rm":
                this.remove(id);
                break;
            case "cs":
                var scr = id + "(";
                if (this.isArray(data)) {
                    scr += "(data[0])";
                    for (var l = 1; l < data.length; l++) {
                        scr += ",(data[" + l + "])"
                    }
                } else {
                    scr += "data"
                }
                scr += ");";
                eval(scr);
                break;
            default:
                alert("Unknow command: " + cmd)
            }
        }
    };
    this.isArray = function (obj) {
        if (obj) {
            return obj.constructor == Array
        }
        return false
    };
    this.buildCall = function (comName, sFunction) {};
    this.icall = function (comName, sFunction) {
        var arg = "";
        if (arguments.length > 2) {
            for (var i = 2; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                var a = arguments[i];
                if (this.isArray(a)) {
                    arg += "arg" + i + "=" + this.stringify(a) + "&"
                } else {
                    if (typeof a == "string") {
                        var t = new Array("_d_", encodeURIComponent(a));
                        arg += "arg" + i + "=" + this.stringify(t) + "&"
                    } else {
                        var t = new Array("_d_", encodeURIComponent(a));
                        arg += "arg" + i + "=" + this.stringify(t) + "&"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (jax_site_type == "1.5") {
            this.submitTask(comName, sFunction, arg)
        } else {
            this.submitITask(comName, sFunction, arg)
        }
    };
    this.call = function (comName, sFunction) {
        var arg = "";
        if (arguments.length > 2) {
            for (var i = 2; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                var a = arguments[i];
                if (this.isArray(a)) {
                    arg += "arg" + i + "=" + this.stringify(a) + "&"
                } else {
                    if (typeof a == "string") {
                        a = a.replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
                        var t = new Array("_d_", encodeURIComponent(a));
                        arg += "arg" + i + "=" + this.stringify(t) + "&"
                    } else {
                        var t = new Array("_d_", encodeURIComponent(a));
                        arg += "arg" + i + "=" + this.stringify(t) + "&"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        this.submitTask(comName, sFunction, arg)
    };
    this.create = function (sParentId, sTag, sId) {
        var objParent = this.$(sParentId);
        objElement = document.createElement(sTag);
        objElement.setAttribute("id", sId);
        if (objParent) {
            objParent.appendChild(objElement)
        }
    };
    this.remove = function (sId) {
        objElement = this.$(sId);
        if (objElement && objElement.parentNode && objElement.parentNode.removeChild) {
            objElement.parentNode.removeChild(objElement)
        }
    };
    this.getFormValues = function (frm) {
        var objForm;
        objForm = this.$(frm);
        if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
            Array.prototype.indexOf = function (elt) {
                var len = this.length;
                var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
                from = (from < 0) ? Math.ceil(from) : Math.floor(from);
                if (from < 0) {
                    from += len
                }
                for (; from < len; from++) {
                    if (from in this && this[from] === elt) {
                        return from
                    }
                }
                return -1
            }
        }
        var postData = new Array();
        if (objForm && objForm.tagName == "FORM") {
            var formElements = objForm.elements;
            var assCheckbox = new Array();
            var assCntIdx = 0;
            var arrayHiddenValues = new Array();
            var arrayHiddenCount = 0;
            if (formElements.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < formElements.length; i++) {
                    if (!formElements[i].name) {
                        continue
                    }
                    if (formElements[i].type && (formElements[i].type == "radio" || formElements[i].type == "checkbox") && formElements[i].checked == false) {
                        continue
                    }
                    var name = formElements[i].name;
                    if (name) {
                        if (formElements[i].type == "select-multiple") {
                            postData[i] = new Array();
                            for (var j = 0; j < formElements[i].length; j++) {
                                if (formElements[i].options[j].selected === true) {
                                    var value = formElements[i].options[j].value;
                                    postData[i][j] = new Array(name, encodeURIComponent(value))
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (formElements[i].type == "checkbox") {
                                if (assCheckbox.indexOf(formElements[i].name) == -1) {
                                    assCheckbox[assCntIdx] = formElements[i].name;
                                    assCntIdx++
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (formElements[i].type == "hidden") {
                                    if (arrayHiddenValues.indexOf(formElements[i].name) == -1) {
                                        arrayHiddenValues[arrayHiddenCount] = formElements[i].name;
                                        arrayHiddenCount++
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    var value = formElements[i].value;
                                    value = value.replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
                                    postData[i] = new Array(name, encodeURIComponent(value))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (arrayHiddenValues.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < arrayHiddenValues.length; i++) {
                    var hiddenElement = document.getElementsByName(arrayHiddenValues[i]);
                    if (hiddenElement) {
                        if (hiddenElement.length > 1) {
                            var curLen = postData.length;
                            postData[curLen] = new Array();
                            for (var j = 0; j < hiddenElement.length; j++) {
                                var value = hiddenElement[j].value;
                                value = value.replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
                                postData[curLen][j] = new Array(arrayHiddenValues[i], encodeURIComponent(value))
                            }
                        } else {
                            var value = hiddenElement[0].value;
                            value = value.replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
                            postData[postData.length] = new Array(arrayHiddenValues[i], encodeURIComponent(value))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (assCheckbox.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < assCheckbox.length; i++) {
                    var objCheckbox = document.getElementsByName(assCheckbox[i]);
                    if (objCheckbox) {
                        if (objCheckbox.length > 1) {
                            var tmpIdx = 0;
                            var curLen = postData.length;
                            postData[curLen] = new Array();
                            for (var j = 0; j < objCheckbox.length; j++) {
                                if (objCheckbox[j].checked) {
                                    var value = objCheckbox[j].value;
                                    value = value.replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
                                    postData[curLen][j] = new Array(assCheckbox[i], encodeURIComponent(value));
                                    tmpIdx++
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (objCheckbox[0].checked) {
                                var value = objCheckbox[0].value;
                                value = value.replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
                                postData[postData.length] = new Array(assCheckbox[i], encodeURIComponent(value))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return postData
    }
}
function jax_iresponse() {
    jax.processIResponse()
}
var jax = new Jax();
```

Please help me.

Comment: Even nuts like me aren't so masochistic as to deal with a gigantic one-line blob of code like that.

Comment: this is usually because your getting back html instead of json. Check the output from the server to debug further.

Comment: Thanks guys for your quick response. But please tell me how do I start to debug this huge piece of code?

Comment: Even after these 5 years, I am still getting down vote on this question. Can't we just close this question forever? I am done with it. I just gave up trying to solve it a long long back. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure anyone should read obfuscated, minified code, but i found this:

```
**xmlhttp.onreadystatechange**=function(){
   if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){
     if(xmlhttp.status==200){
jax.doneLoadingFunction(); 
**jax.processResponse**(xmlhttp.responseText)}

else{}
}
};
```

Which returns a js error on line 1 :))

Are you allowed to use ** with variable names in js?

Comment: Most likely, OP was trying to make those words appear bold here.

Comment: was a 1 line x 10000 characters code snippet when i read it, thought it was a minifier error

Comment: It's correct, alinn. I was trying to make that line of code look bold. "**" is not present in original script.

Answer (score 0):

check if your bug is  not here line 296

```
var result = eval(responseTxt);
```

What are you getting as a response? is it html, json?
Check also for notices in your backend script,
You can check this with the console/inspector in chrome (f12) , network tab.

It could be even be a debug output/notice/error from your backend script.

If you open it with firefox, i think firebug shows you a JSON tab if your response is in correct json format.

Comment: If the response is json you can copy in in the console and see if it prints out; var x= [paste response here]; then just x and run it

Comment: Great, alinn. when I open this script in IE it shows 'script error' character 5161 which is var result = eval(responseTxt); what is this error.

Comment: eval treats responseText as javascript or json, so it expects it to be just that; the problem is in the response you are getting. You have to check the response text itself, there is no JS bug.

Comment: If it's live i can check it for you, i can't be sure without the ajax response text

Comment: It is not live. How can I check the response? I mean what do I need to do to see the response?

Comment: either do it like i said in firebug (ie console cant do it, i think) or just run the ajax url in directly in a browser or console.log(responseText) - console.log will only work in chrome or Firefox. How are you json-encoding in the backend language?

Comment: I just checked it in Firebug console it shows                    'invalid regular expression flag h
_firebugInjectedEvaluate
_firebugEvalEvent() '. Is it helping?